# Why is this js not showing up in my rails view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so i have a campaign javascript that i need to get for a site. The site is under ssl and the campaign is not so the browser blocks the request

So to work around i am doing the request via the application_controller

```
before_filter :get_campaign 

def get_campaign
  uri = URI.parse("http://us1.campaign-archive1.com/generate-js/?u=2f77d2f8c77398c0b064223ba&fid=1&show=3")
  begin
    @campaign = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).body
  end
end
```

and in the view i do

```
      %script{:language => "javascript", :type => "text/javascript"}
        = @campaign.try(:html_safe)
```

because the `@campaign` is a document.write string...but for some reason its not writing....am i missing something or is there a better way to achieve this

UPDATE

After looking at the console in chrome i see this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Here is my generated code

```html
  <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                  document.write("<div class=\"display_archive\"><div class=\"campaign\">08\/29\/2012 - <a href=\"http:\/\/us1.campaign-archive1.com\/?u=2f77d2f8c77398c0b064223ba&id=4c4d33ed6f\" title=\"Ten Fun Facts and Figures from Gen Con Indy 2012\" target=\"_blank\">Ten Fun Facts and Figures from Gen Con Indy 2012<\/a><\/div><\/div>");
                  <br>
                  <div class='display_archive'></div>
                  <div class='campaign'>
                    Select
                    <a href='http://eepurl.com/jkmGT' target='_blank'>HERE</a>
                    to sign up for our newsletter! 
                  </div>
                </script>
```

Comment: first check if `@campaign` is empty or not.

Comment: @campaign is not empty...i just noticed an error in the console..i will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript fragment you're downloading contains characters which can't be used unescaped and you're preventing the escaping from happening. Usually one wraps this sort of stuff in CDATA tags. The haml javascript filter does this for you if CDATA support is turned on (it is by default for XHTML):

```
:javascript
  #{@campaign}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have HTML inside a *script* tag? I'm pretty sure that's what the problem is, you should delete everything from and including *br* in your @campaign.

```
@campaign.gsub!(/<br.*/, "")
```